# Why does SELECT @@VERSION return previous version after installing new SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2019

First I installed SQL Server 2012 for learning. Because it doesn't take too much memory.

But later I need a SQL Server for development so I installed the latest version of SQL Server 2019 Developer edition.

After installation, I check the version of SQL Server in SSMS using

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

and I get:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)   Feb 10 2012 19:39:15   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200:)
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Side note, you said you installed SQL Server 2012 for "learning", but your version says you are using Enterprise; that is *not* free (far from it). A 2 core pack for SQL Server 2019 Enterprise costs $13,748 (so if you're running something like an 8 Core processor you should be paying $54,992 to use it)! You should be installing Express or Developer versions if you are planning to learn. The former is completely free, and the latter is free for non-production environments.

Comment: Multiple SQL versions can be installed next to each other. Did you uninstall the previous version?

Answer (score 4):

If you **already** had SQL Server 2012 installed, then the SQL Server 2019 Developer edition wasn't installed as the "default, unnamed" instance - since there can only ever be one of those.

So when you installed SQL Server 2019, you **must have** chosen an instance name - use that instance name when connecting, e.g. use `.\INSTANCE` or `(local)\INSTANCE` to connect to the **new** version of SQL Server installed